# python-telegram-bot error "TypeError: __dict__ slot disallowed: we already got one"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
import logging

from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)

## MANY FUNCTIONS HERE....

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(myToken)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            GENDER: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Boy|Girl|Other)$'), gender)],
            PHOTO: [MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo), CommandHandler('skip', skip_photo)],
            LOCATION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.location, location),
                CommandHandler('skip', skip_location),
            ],
            BIO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, bio)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's an basic example of python-telegrom-bot at gitHub. It runs on my computer with jupyter and pycharm ide... But when i try to run it on AWS i get this error ;

i try it with different versions of it but couldnt solve...:(

[ERROR PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqCnf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please include information on which version of `python-telegram-bot` you're using and which version of Python you are using (locally and on AWS). For example, you can show the output of `python -m telegram`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but inside of docker container.

I just changed the version of python from `3.6` to `3.7` and rebuild container. This fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of python-telegram-bot have problems with Python 3.6.
Instead of changing your python version, you can install an older version of python-telegram-bot.

`pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same abnormal problem
telegram-bot is used here
https://github.com/vicalloy/telegram-shell-bot

The python version is version 3.6.8 ,
The operating system is centos 7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WcNc.jpg)