# TypeError and error with importing packages

Tags: python, telegram

I'm using `ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`, `Python 3.6.9` and `python-telegram-bot-13.12`

I wrote my code on ubuntu 20 with python 3.7 and it was ok, now i need to rewrite it for ubuntu 18.
but the same mistakes are constantly appearing

errors:

```
skye@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/skye/Desktop/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skye/Desktop/bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, Filters
  File "/home/skye/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .updater import Updater
  File "/home/skye/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 55, in <module>
    class Updater(Generic[CCT, UD, CD, BD]):
  File "/home/skye/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 198, in Updater
    dispatcher: Dispatcher[CCT, UD, CD, BD] = None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1143, in __getitem__
    orig_bases=self.__orig_bases__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 978, in __new__
    self = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 137, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 133, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
TypeError: __dict__ slot disallowed: we already got one
```

my code:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, Filters
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
import re

TOKEN = ''

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='213',
    password='11111',
    database='bot_database'
)
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()


db_cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscribers (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(255),
        first_name VARCHAR(255),
        last_name VARCHAR(255)
    )
''')
db_connection.commit()


db_cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_logs (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(255),
        first_name VARCHAR(255),
        action_type VARCHAR(255),
        action_text TEXT,
        timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
''')
db_connection.commit()


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user = update.effective_user
    user_id = user.id


    user_logs = get_user_logs(user_id)


    with db_connection.cursor() as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE user_id = %s', (user_id,))
        existing_user = db_cursor.fetchone()

        if not existing_user:
            db_cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO subscribers (user_id, username, first_name, last_name)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
            ''', (user_id, user.username, user.first_name, user.last_name))
            db_connection.commit()

    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(
        fr'Привет, {user.mention_markdown_v2()}\!',
        reply_markup=None
    )



def log_user_action(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user = update.effective_user
    user_id = user.id
    username = user.username
    first_name = user.first_name
    action_text = update.message.text.lstrip()

    if action_text.startswith("/"):
        action_type = "command"
        action_text = re.sub('^/', '', action_text) 
    else:
        action_type = "message"

    with db_connection.cursor() as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO user_logs (user_id, username, first_name, action_type, action_text, timestamp)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        ''', (user_id, username, first_name, action_type, action_text, datetime.now()))

        db_connection.commit()




def get_user_logs(user_id):
    with db_connection.cursor() as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.execute('''
            SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE user_id = %s ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        ''', (user_id,))
        user_logs = db_cursor.fetchall()

        columns = [column[0] for column in db_cursor.description]

        user_logs_dict = []
        for log in user_logs:
            log_dict = dict(zip(columns, log))
            user_logs_dict.append(log_dict)

    return user_logs_dict


def test_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('тестовая команда!')

def test1(update, context):
    if update.message:
        image_url = 'https://www.rainforest-alliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/capybara-square-1.jpg.optimal.jpg'
        context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=image_url, caption='Это тестовая картинка.')


def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("test", test_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("test1", test1))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.update.message & ~Filters.command, log_user_action))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I reinstalled python-telegram-bot and tried to use another version,  used other libraries besides python-telegram-bot, I tried not to use some imports to avoid their conflict. Most of these errors are due to the fact that python is on version 3.6 plus the old version of the libraries, but ubuntu 18 does not support python 3.7, and i need to use native components

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: There appears to be a [known incompatibility between Python 3.6 and this decades versions of Python telegram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622269/python-telegram-bot-error-typeerror-dict-slot-disallowed-we-already-got-o) Version 13 was recommended as the latest to use with Python 3.6.